# Numbering equations in a math paper - can I restart my numbering for each new theorem and its proof?

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

In a paper that I am working on, the numbering of equations in the proofs has gotten pretty large, even with my removing a bunch of numbering of equations that I do not reference back to in later parts of the paper.

The numbering is in the twenties now, e.g., $(19)$, $(20)$, ...

and I usually reference back to them like this,

> "...then $(19)$ and $(20)$ imply that ...."

Is there another way I could number my equations instead?  I don't want to reach equation $(100)$ ... that seems like not a good idea.

My question is:

Could I instead just number my equations per theorem statement - proof?  So that for a new theorem and its proof, I could restart the numbering ... back to $(1)$, $(2)$, ... $(5)$ ...

I am saving Roman numerals ($i$, $ii$, $iii$, $iv$) for necessary conditions in the theorem statements and don't plan to use them in the proofs.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are about to have 100-ish equations, you are likely to partition your text into several chapters. Restarting the equation counter per chapter is probably preferable (anjd easily done; TeX (which I presume you use) can even automatically turn a reference "$(5)$" into "chapter 3, $(5)$" or similar in case you need to reference a far away equation now and then

Comment: Awesome suggestions, @HagenvonEitzen - thanks so much.  I'm happy to accept your comment as an answer, if you want to convert it :)

Comment: I've removed the proof theory tag, since that isn't appropriate (proof theory is a specific branch of mathematical logic, not the general theory of how to write proofs).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having 100 equations.  Also note that you do not need to label all of your equations.  Using latex \nonumber or \notag will give an equation without number, or $\mbox{\begin{align*} \end{align*}}$ will do the same.  Restarting equations would be confusing unless they are labeled by chapter or section (as in the Hagen answer), like equation 3.10. However,   that is usually for books and likely not relevant for papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about to have 100-ish equations, you are likely to partition your text into several chapters. Restarting the equation counter per chapter is probably preferable (and easily done). If you are using $\LaTeX$ (which you probably should anyway), you can even automatically turn a reference "(5)" into "chapter 3, (5)" or similar in case you need to reference a far away equation now and then. For details on the latter, you may want to ask follow-up questions on [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com).